# How can we unite all vedic sampradaya?

Tags: advaita, vaishnavism, shaivism, vishishtadvaita, dvaita

In this Kaliyuga there are many types of schools which are based on their believes. These believes may sometimes lead to quarrel. Without hurting their believes how we can live harmoniously?

Comment: By respecting each others beliefs.

Comment: @Wikash it is impossible.

Comment: No, it is possible. We do not need to convince each other. Just respect other beliefs and ideas.

Comment: @Wikash follower of dvaita(Madhva sampradaya) don't respect advaita at all. They don't think adi Shankaracharya as avatar of Shiva instead they treat them very keeenly. The Madhva Vijaya granthas also treat adi Shankaracharya the same way. If madhvas can't stop reading those Vijaya granthas how can these sampradaya live harmoniously?

Comment: By respecting the different opinions.

Comment: You don't have to respect other people’s beliefs. Just try to respect people whatever their beliefs might be. You can be indifferent towards other beliefs, neither respecting them nor scorn them. So, respect people and not their beliefs. That will suffice. Thus you can live harmoniously with all Hindus, and even non-Hindus.

Answer (score 2):

https://youtu.be/JC3YiO8ZIsE

**If you understand Hindi, this video is perfect reply to your question.**

Adi Shankaracharya is indeed the avataar of Lord Shiva and most of the followers of Madhva Sampradaya knows this. Just because a group of people reject the fact, you can't just blame the entire community. Focus of Adi Shankaracharya's appearance was to demolish nastikvaad and to re-establish importance of studying Vedas. Later on the Vaishnav Acharyas : Madhvacharya, Ramanujacharya, Nimbarkacharya, Vallabh Acharya and many others focused on propagating development of faith towards Supreme God Krishna or Vishnu and hence it was required to overpower the Adwaitvaad so that Vaishnavism might flourish. If Adwait siddhanta prevails, Vaishnavism will have no existence as both are contradicting to each other. This very fact both the Adwaitins and Vaishnavs should understand and thus we can live harmonically. What Wikash is saying to you is actually correct - "Respect the opinions of each other."